# Android Auto installed but "invisible"

Tags: android-10, android-auto

I have Android Auto installed, but I can't run it:

1. I can navigate to Android Audio app's page in Google Play app and I see "Uninstall", but I don't see "Open".
2. I cannot see this app's icon in Nova Launcher (or any other launcher).
3. When I install this app directly from .apk file the "Launch" button in confirmation message box is grayed.

Is this something with my Android (10) or my gear (DooGee S88 Plus)?

This is the first time, I have such situation. So far, in the past 10+ years of using Android, I could only see apps that I can install and run or that I can't install. I have never seen before an app that I can install, but can't run, since this seems pointless.

BTW: When I tap "Uninstall" in Google Play then, after something that looks like uninstallation process, I don't see "Install" button again, but "Update" instead (which would suggest that application hasn't been actually uninstalled). This is also very weird and also I have this situation for the first time in my Android life. What is this, what is causing this or what am I missing in the above picture?

Comment: Do you know that Android Auto is discontinued? May be Google now tries to force the users to use their assistant instead? https://www.androidpolice.com/2021/08/18/it-might-be-the-end-of-the-road-for-android-auto-on-phone-screens/

Comment: "*I don't see "Install" button again, but "Update" instead (which would suggest that application hasn't been actually uninstalled)*" this usually means that Android Auto is installed as a system app, thus cannot be uninstalled completely, only restored to factory state.

Comment: @AndrewT. I know that. But I wouldn't expect to have a system app that you cannot actually run. It is pointless to have installed / not uninstallable / restorable app that you cannot actually run and use, right?

Comment: @Robert Didn't know that, but the screenshot in an article you shared seems to be suggesting that it is discontinued only for regular use on phone. I have a Android Auto enabled car (and screen), namely Toyota Aygo, and I wanted to use Android Auto like that, not on the phone. I understand the above mentioned screenshot the way that I can still use Android Auto with designated cars. Only... I am unable to run it :\

Comment: And... still the question was intended to be more generic like. I was wondering if this is "only me" (DooGee / Android 10) or if you know any other examples of an app that you can successfully answer (Google Play store claims that it is available for this particular phone), but you cannot run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Since Android 10, Android Auto is integrated as a system app but hidden for phone users. Users may have to install Android Auto for Phone Screens app to use it on their phones.**

According to [Android Auto Help - I can't find the Android Auto app on my phone](https://support.google.com/androidauto/answer/9468382),

> Starting with Android 10, Android Auto is built into the phone as a technology that enables your phone to connect to your car display. [...]
>
> If you don't have an Android Auto compatible car or prefer to access Android Auto on your phone screen, there are 3 options:
>
> - If you're upgrading your phone from Android 9 to Android 10, make sure that your phone already has Android Auto installed before you upgrade. If so, the app icon will carry over to your newly upgraded device.
> - You can use [Google Backup](https://support.google.com/android/answer/2819582) to backup and restore from another device that already has Android Auto app installed.
> - You can also go to the Play Store and download [Android Auto for Phone Screens](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.projection.gearhead.phonescreen), which is only available on Android 10 or higher devices. Once you install the app, you can continue to use Android Auto on your phone screen.

---

According to GSM Arena, [Doogee S88 Pro](https://www.gsmarena.com/_doogee_s88_pro-10754.php) comes with Android 10 already. Thus, Android Auto app is hidden by default and users need to install Android Auto for Phone Screens if they want to use it from their phone.

On the other hand, [Google Pixel 3a](https://www.gsmarena.com/google_pixel_3a-9408.php) comes with Android 9 and Android Auto pre-installed. Thus, when it's updated to Android 10 (and beyond), the app icon is still shown on the app drawer.

Comment: Thank you! I will only add that Android Auto for Phone Screens does not work / isn't available for all Android 10 devices. I have just opened (on my PC) an [app page](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.projection.gearhead.phonescreen) using Google account that I use with my Doogee S88 Plus and even though it has Android 10 preinstalled, I can clearly see _This app is not available for any of your devices_ message.